# Singular or plural noun: "... all had a wonderful summer" vs. "... wonderful summers"

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct when addressing an audience or more than one person? Or are both equally valid?

> I hope you have all **had wonderful summers**!

OR

> I hope you have all **had a wonderful summer**!

Comment: Your reference is to one specific summer, so it's singular.

Comment: @Centaurus +1, but perhaps *intent* matters: *summer* as *season*, or *summer* as *holiday*. With the latter, the *summers* form doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: @Centaurus Not a totally convincing argument. 'They both came a cropper' doesn't necessarily refer to the same misadventure, but the singular is idiomatic. And with 'Welcome back to the course. I hope you've all had a good holiday /  good holidays', either is available, even though there is only one holiday period involved and the 'going away' count sense isn't necessarily implied. As Lawrence implies, focus (considering individuals rather than the group as a whole) permits the plural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Context is everything.  Without any supporting context, I agree with you that both singular and plural nouns are acceptable.  The sentence given by the OP, however, is directed to a specific audience.  I would find it awkward to say  "I hope you have all had wonderful summers"   or "Have nice weekends". when addressing a group.

Comment: @Centaurus I agree. Much better comment.

Answer (score 2):

Replace summer with another word to see how it fits:

> I hope you have all had wonderful dinners

Sounds clumsy - you're implying that each individual has had more than one dinner.

> I hope you have all had wonderful times

Even clumsier.

So:

> I hope you have all had a wonderful summer
>
> I hope you have all had a wonderful dinner
>
> I hope you have all had a wonderful time

So, while many of them have had the same experience, each person has only experienced the one thing

Comment: Compare *I hope all those different people had wonderful summers* TO *I hope all those different people had a wonderful summer.* The latter makes it seem like all those different people had the same wonderful summer. Try it with *lives*: Compare *I hope all those different people had wonderful lives* TO *I hope all those different people had a wonderful life.* In both cases, the latter seems wrong.

Comment: Nope - I don't see it.

Comment: I'll stand pat.

Comment: Perhaps an even more telling example is 'A good time was had by all.' There is a massification involved. Obviously, it's not open to deep scrutiny – they didn't all have exactly the same experiences – but it's idiomatic, paraphrasable by 'They all enjoyed themselves'. With @Richard Kayser's 'They all [lived] wonderful lives', the massification _might well be_ overdoing it: the 'universal grinder approach'  {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_grinder)} is less to be recommended. So 'time', 'summer', but 'lives'. And I'd say that 'holiday / holidays' give different emphases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have no issues with "A good time was had by all." I have tried to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope you have all had wonderful **summers**!
>
> OR
>
> I hope **each of you** **had** a wonderful summer!

In the first sentence, we have a plural audience (*you have all*). We can also assume that each person had their own form of *summer* vacation, independent of the others. Given that, the object should be plural, i.e., **summers**, not **summer**.

**To explain further**: If members of the plural audience had been served the same meal or gone on the same day trip, and then reconvened, one would say:

> I hope you have all had a wonderful meal OR I hope you have all had a
>   wonderful day trip. [singular objects]

On the other hand, if they had all gone their own separate ways for meals or day trips, and then reconvened, one would say:

> I hope you have all had wonderful meals OR I hope you have all had
>   wonderful day trips. [plural objects]

I have consciously refrained from rewriting the OP's example.